# How do I edit this interactive PowerPoint workflow?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

This presentation allows me to click "yes" or "no" and takes me to a logical path according to my answers.

How do I edit the workflow so I can customize it to my needs

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-Datacenter-09a81fc6

Comment: What do you mean? U just normally edit it. I was able to change the text,add animations and change fonts and backgrounds without any issue. As far as editing the workflow goes, be sure to edit the conditions only and not the structure.

Comment: @Gutsygibbon I'm not sure where the branching logic and "workflow" is located.

Answer (score 1):

The logic/workflow are in the head of whoever created the presentation or more likely on a piece of paper or storyboard.  It's implemented via action settings.  Open the presentation, go to, for example, Slide 2.  Click on the "Stop-Database Availablity Group" rectangle to select it, then on the Insert tab, click Action.

You'll see that the Action setting is Hyperlink to: 3. Stop-... etc.

Click the downarrow to the right of that and you'll get other choices; if you click Slide, PPT will give you a list of the slides in the presentation.  Click the one you'd like to link to and you're done.